# Setting/changing default Java MaxHeapSize or changing default JVM command settings

Tags: java, jvm

I'm using a python script that calls the jvm. Unfortunately, the script doesn't allow me to pass arguments to the jvm command, so I can't bump up the max heap size via the `Xmx` flags.

Is there a way to set/change the default `MaxHeapSize` allowed or set/change default arguments for any jvm calls?

---

`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` from the answer below worked for me:

```sh
# echo $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
-Xmx10g
# java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep MaxHeapSize
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx10g
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 10737418240                               {product} {command line}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set JVM arguments via [JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#tooloptions) environment variable, e.g.

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xmx10g
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to get around the issues you are having is to create a batch file (type and implementation depends on platform). The batch file should execute Java, and you can execute the batch file from python